# How to get the contents of parenthesis by regex?

Tags: php, regex

I want to get the contents of parenthesis within a string in PHP by regular expression. I tried this regex

```
preg_match_all('/\((.*)?\)/', $string, $match);
```

But this get the content between the first `(` and last `)`. How can I get the content of every `( )`separately to make the array of match?

Comment: Why do you feel that you need regular expressions?

Comment: Alternatively `preg_replace_callback` and a recursive `(?R)` regex. (Search for dupes. Unless you meant just the *inner* and not *every* parenthesis pair.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `.*` with `[^\)]*`

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match_all('/\(([^)]*)\)/', $string, $match);
```